# What if compaction is disabled when only insertion matters?

Tags: cassandra

In cassandra, compaction is much needed for faster query retrieval when so many versions of column scattered across different SSTables. Compaction is best strategy to have when sequence of updates on same column or deletion is done. But Compaction is heavy resource utilization process. But in my application I only use Cassandra for inserting record and viewing them. But key space size may grow in GB.. And it is going to hold more than millions of records. Here for me,insertion only matters. I am not going to update columns or delete the column. My simple deletion will be on entire key space. Now My doubt is May I **disable compaction**? will compaction disabling degrade querying performance?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) It depends on your data model.

2) The complex part of the Cassandra is the read performance and the compaction improves it.

3) Even if you are not going to delete or update the same column but if you are planning to insert new column to same row then disabling compaction certainly hamper your read performance,because it will increase the number of disk seeks.

4) Apart from that compaction does the job of tombstone collection but your deletion is entire keyspace deletion so that is not an issue.

5) Compaction merges row fragment together, removes expired tombstones and rebuilds the indexes none of these is needed in your case. So theoretically you can turn off the compaction. But with more no of sstable and large data if the bloom filters false positive can affect your read performance. see bloom filters here: [Cassandra Architecture Overview](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureOverview)

Comment: I am not going to insert the new column to the same row. It is like one time row insert. If the row is inserted that will not be touched again.Now is it necessary to have compaction for my scenario?